# First Letter Big and Inset into the next line?

Tags: fonts, text, lettrine

[image]

How to make that "F". I'm also using the `multicol` package

Comment: See the `lettrine` and `drop-cap` tags for many examples.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186701/thoughts-on-turning-this-dropcap-lettrine-code-into-a-macro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the package `lettrine` to do the job.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % you want true small caps
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Beginning}

\lettrine{F}{ew would quarrel} about the correct way to break boiled
eggs, but, as you probably know, there was even a civil war caused
by this very important question in the island of Lilliput. You may
also know that computer scientists took the names \emph{big-endian}
and \emph{little-endian} from Swift's `Gulliver's travels'.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But you seem to want a slightly different output, with the *lettrine* (that means “drop cap” in French) sticking up. If you type

```
\lettrine[loversize=0.5]{F}{ew would quarrel}
```

then the output would be

[image]

But you don't need to add `loversize=0.5` every time. Just add the appropriate setting in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % you want true small caps
\usepackage{lettrine}

% lettrine settings
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.5}
%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Beginning}

\lettrine{F}{ew would quarrel} about the correct way to break boiled
eggs, but, as you probably know, there was even a civil war caused
by this very important question in the island of Lilliput. You may
also know that computer scientists took the names \emph{big-endian}
and \emph{little-endian} from Swift's `Gulliver's travels'.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personal opinion: I'd never use drop caps *and* Times.

Answer (score 2):

Note: See "[Typesetting dropped capitals with LaTeX](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/doc/lettrine.pdf)"
See also "[How to increase the size of first character in a chapter (Drop-Caps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/how-to-increase-the-size-of-first-character-in-a-chapter-drop-caps)"

I've been using the lettrine package for some time:

[\usepackage{lettrine}](https://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine?lang=en)

I've made the lettrine package available via a simple definition:

```
%___________ Define \plett ____________
\makeatletter
\def\plett#1{%
\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\myfirstletter]%
\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\myrestofword]
\lettrine[lines=3]{\myfirstletter}{\trimright{\myrestofword}}
}
\makeatother
```

I find that `[lines=3]` e.g. the height of the dropped capitol in the number of lines, suits most of my needs, but can be easily adjusted.

A typical example of how to apply the `\plett` code would be:

```
\plett{Fire can exist} in many forms. Over the course of human history, we have utilized fire in it’s many likenesses to accomplish what we otherwise could not. \par
```

For added effect, I've adjusted the color of the initial character with the following:

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{BrickRed}}  % See LaTeX/Colors
```

Where I've define BrickRed as:

```
\definecolor{BrickRed}{RGB}{144,44,30}
```

Lastly, I added the `\trimright` function (from an SE [posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69767/trimming-whitespace-around-text-like-ltrim-rtrim-and-trim)) that is called in the `\plett` function (See 'Define \trimleft & \trimright' in the MWE.).

```
%_________________________________________

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}


\definecolor{BrickRed}{RGB}{144,44,30} 

%___________ Define \plett ____________
    \makeatletter
    \def\plett#1{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\myfirstletter]%
    \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\myrestofword]
    \lettrine[lines=3]{\myfirstletter}{\trimright{\myrestofword}}
    }
    \makeatother

%________ Define \trimleft & \trimright _______
% Trimming whitespace around text (like LTRIM, RTRIM and TRIM)
\begingroup
  %
  % This plain TeX code uses the prefix "tsp", and defines
  % \trim, \trimleft, and \trimright.
  %
  \catcode`@=11
  \long\gdef\trim#1{\trimleft{\trimright{#1}}}
  %
  % Trimming spaces on the right is done by repeatedly calling \unskip
  % until \lastskip is zero.  We start with \hskip0pt\relax to stop
  % \trimright from trimming spaces _before_ #1 in case this only
  % contains spaces.
  %
  \long\gdef\trimright#1{\hskip0pt\relax #1\tsp@right}
  \gdef\tsp@right
    {\unskip\ifdim0pt=\lastskip\else\expandafter\tsp@right\fi}
  %
  % Trimming spaces on the left is done by repeatedly using \futurelet
  % to test the first token, and dispatching depending on what is found.
  % Expandable tokens are expanded; most assignments are performed;
  % spaces are ignored; groups are entered.  The loop ends when
  % encountering \tsp@left@end.
  %
  \long\gdef\trimleft#1{\tsp@left#1\tsp@left@end}
  \global\let\tsp@left@end\relax
  \gdef\tsp@left{\expandafter\tsp@left@look}
  \gdef\tsp@left@look{\futurelet\tsp@token\tsp@left@test}
  \gdef\tsp@left@test
    {%
      \typeout{\meaning\tsp@token}%
      \expandafter\ifx\noexpand\tsp@token\tsp@token
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
      {% Expandable token => expand again.
        \let\tsp@next\tsp@left
      }%
      {%
        \ifcat\tsp@token\relax
          % Non-expandable primitive: build \tsp@<meaning>.
          % Note that primitives for which I haven't defined
          % \tsp@<meaning> just give \relax, which stops
          % trimming cleanly.
          \begingroup
            \escapechar-1%
            \global\expandafter\let\expandafter\tsp@next
              \csname tsp@\meaning\tsp@token\endcsname
          \endgroup
        \else
          % Character token.
          \ifcat\tsp@token\bgroup % Begin-group: do; continue trimming
            \bgroup\let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
          \else
            \ifcat\tsp@token\egroup % End-group: do; continue trimming
              \egroup\let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
            \else
              \ifcat\tsp@token\space % Space: remove; continue trimming
                \let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
              \else % Anything else: stop trimming
                \let\tsp@next\relax
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
      \tsp@next
    }%
  \gdef\tsp@gobble@token{\afterassignment\tsp@left\let\tsp@token= }
  %
  % Helpers for defining primitives.
  %
  \long\gdef\tsp@swap#1{#1\tsp@gobble@token}
  \gdef\tsp@assignment{\afterassignment\tsp@left}
  %
  % Various primitives
  %
  \global \let \tsp@unskip     \tsp@gobble@token
  \global \expandafter \let \csname tsp@ \endcsname \tsp@gobble@token
  \global \let \tsp@begingroup \tsp@swap
  \global \let \tsp@endgroup   \tsp@swap
  \global \let \tsp@def        \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@edef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@gdef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@xdef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@let        \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@futurelet  \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@global     \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@long       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@protected  \tsp@assignment
  \gdef\tsp@hskip#1{\begingroup\afterassignment\tsp@hskip@\skip0= }
  \gdef\tsp@hskip@{\endgroup\tsp@left}
  %
  % We must end when seeing \tsp@left@end (normally \relax)
  %
  \long\gdef\tsp@relax#1%
    {%
      \begingroup
        \def\tsp@left@end{\tsp@left@end}%
        \expandafter
      \endgroup
      \ifx#1\tsp@left@end
      \else
        \expandafter\tsp@left
      \fi
    }
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{BrickRed}}  % See LaTeX/Colors
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\rmfamily}
% \renewcommand*{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape}   % for French

 \plett{Fire can exist} in many forms. Over the course of human history, we have utilized fire in it’s many likenesses to accomplish what we otherwise could not. \par

\end{document}
%_________________________________________
```

Works nicely!

[image: The lettrine package has several options for dropped capitols.]