# Drop cap using yfonts and yinipar on a double-spaced text

Tags: drop-cap

In reference to drop cap letters, and the thread

[How can I create documents in LaTeX using a calligraphic first letter for chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-can-i-create-documents-in-latex-using-a-calligraphic-first-letter-for-chapte)

can anybody tell how to get rid of the space problem that occurs when one uses

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts,color}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
   \yinipar{\color{red}P}hysical properties [...]
\end{document}
```

What I get looks like this:

[image: What I get looks like this:]

How to make it look like this?

[image: How to make it look like this?]

I tried lettrine and various fonts, but was not satisfied with the effect they provided.

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't see any space problem in the given code!

Comment: I have no issue either.

Comment: @egreg : The problem occurs because my document is double spaced, and `\yinipar` cannot handle any spacing other than `\singlespacing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the desired result with `lettrine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts,color,lettrine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\renewcommand{\LettrineFont}{\initfamily\color{red}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.5em}}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0.15}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{P}{hysical} properties and
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\onehalfspacing` change the value of `\DefaultLraise`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts,color,lettrine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand{\LettrineFont}{\initfamily\color{red}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.5em}}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{-0.1}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{P}{hysical} properties and
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. Tha nks a ton.
I am leaving this comment of gratitude, since I cannot vote the answer up due to lack of sufficient reputation here.

Comment: @kvaibhav Note that you can accept an answer by clicking on the greyed-out tick at the top left of the answer which helped you most. You can do this regardless of reputation ;). (You will even get a couple of points yourself if you do this as accepting answers is an important way to identify useful solutions to other users with similar questions.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts,color,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
   \yinipar{\color{red}L}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So is the difference that you need to include the line breaks you want? That is, what is different in your code? Admittedly, the OP's example can't possibly reproduce the problem so we can only guess, but I noticed that your code seems to follow the line breaks you want.

Comment: @cfr Just in case, to make it clear edited my answer.

Comment: The solution you've suggested produces what I have shown above. I need to the initial letter to occur at proper place.

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan  I guess I figured out the exact root of the problem. 
The problem occurs because my document is double spaced, and `\yinipar`       cannot handle any spacing other than `\singlespacing` .