# Make 1 letter big

Tags: calligraphy

I'm writing something using article and I'm trying to make 1 letter big and have 2 lines directly next to it, like here: [image: Example]

How would I achieve so?

I tried the following code:

```
\lettrine[lines=2 ]{\textbf{A}}{}
```

but I need the letter A even bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: [How can I create documents in LaTeX using a calligraphic first letter for chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/769/134144) might be interesting if this single letter is the first letter of the first word in this paragraph.

Comment: Try the `lettrine` package.

Comment: @leandriis I tried the code from the post you mentioned, but I want my letter to be even bigger. How do I make it even larger?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide MWE (Minimal working Example, a small complete document, which can be compiled as it is) ,which reproduce or illustrate your problem. Help us to help you!

Comment: @PeterWilson Could you please give me a code example? I am already usng lettrine, but I failed to make it work.

Comment: @Ricardo - please provide more information about what you've tried so far with the `lettrine` package and its `\lettrine` macro. Statements such as "I am already using lettrine but I failed to make it work" are simply too vague to be actionable.

Comment: @Mico I edited my post with a code example.

Comment: Is this big letter the first letter of a paragraph?  Is text supposed to wrap below it or is it merely a label for several lines appearing to the right?  A full example, beginning with `\documentclass` on what you have tried would go a long way to helping us to understand your actual request.

Comment: @Ricardo - If making the letter 2 lines tall isn't enough, is anything stopping you from writing `\lettrine[lines=3]{\textbf{A}}{}`? And if 3 still isn't enough, there's 4, 5, 6, and so on.

Comment: @Mico That's exactly what I tried but changing the number isn't making the letter any bigger.

Comment: @Ricardo, since you still not provide MWE, we cant test   your code and and confirm your result.. You left us to guessing what is going wrong at you :-(.

Comment: no an example should be something that starts \documentclass, ends \end{document} that shows the issue, you should be able to use lines, perhaps you need to add the `fix-cm` package (a wild guess on my part)  but if you provided an example, we wouldn't need to guess.